# Results displayed in Bsh window instead of Eclipse console window while running a program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

While running a set of code in Eclipse, the results are not displayed in the Eclipse console window... Instead "Bhs Console" window opens up and displays the following:

`bsh % BeanShell 1.3.0 - by Pat Niemeyer (pat@pat.net)`

Please help me out to sort it...
I want the results in the Eclipse console window...

Comment: We can't help if we don't have any of your code to look at.

Comment: Adding code:

publicclassAlternateStringArray {

publicstaticvoid main(String[] args) {

String str= "Welcome";

char[] strChars = str.toCharArray();

for(inti = 0; i <strChars.length; i += 2) {

System.out.println(strChars[i]);

}
}
}

Comment: Under your run configuration do you have enabled the "Allocate console (necessary for input)" checkbox?

Comment: Yes... I do have "Allocate console (necessary for input)" checkbox and its checked too...

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to multiple main function in a src folder in eclipse. we know that only one main function call from the src folder. I think thats why that bsh console display while executing the java program.

Solution:-

In the eclipse you can do following steps...

Step 1:-you just right click on the src file.

Step 2:-select "Run as" from the drop down menu then select "Run configuration".

Step 3:-Now you can type a project name and main class name of the src file.

Step 4:-Then Press a Apply Button.

Step 5:-Now you can run src file.

Hope you will not find any bsh window. you will find your result in console....!!!!!